# Screw modifier creating extra faces

Tags: modeling, screw-modifier

I'm using Blender 2.83.5 I have a profile that I'm using with the **Screw Modifier**.  For some reason it's creating extra faces.  How can I fix this so only one face is created?

**Profile Below:**

[image: Screw Profile]

**Use Screw Modifier:**

[image: Screw Mod]

**Extra faces are create somehow:**

[image: facesextra]

**If I delete a face another one is behind it.**

[image]

PS:  This is what I was following
https://youtu.be/R8tXe5oCYXg?t=245

Uploaded blend file
[image]

Comment: Consider a single profile (not 3 in one) screw and array.

Comment: yes you've created 3 different edges as seen in your first picture, so the 3 are screwing, why did you create 3 edges?

Comment: @moonboots  Followed a tutorial to make a three start threaded screw
https://youtu.be/R8tXe5oCYXg?t=245

Comment: Hello, did you make sure you don't have double geometry ? Right click > Merge > By distance in edit mode

Comment: Could you upload the .blend here https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ to avoid guesses? My guess though is the screw isn't height enough.

Comment: @lemon I uploaded / added it to the question and numbered the steps 1, 2, 3 showing what I get before and after the modifier

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is an extra vertex on the base shapes:

[image]

Comment: Thanks!!!  That may explain why merge by distance wasn't doing what I expected it to do.

Answer (score 0):

You have too many iterations, and are therefore creating too much geometry.

From the [manual](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/modifiers/generate/screw.html#screw-modifier)

> Iterations
>
> Number of revolutions.

Therefore, with 3 revolutions, you are creating multiple faces. Just reduce it to one in this case.

Comment: isn't this 3 x 120 degrees hence each profile "bit"  does a 360 screw and ends below itself?

Comment: @batFINGER  Correct
This is what I followed
https://youtu.be/R8tXe5oCYXg?t=245

Comment: @batFINGER This would be true if the screw offset was 0, but here it is 2 mm

Comment: @Gorgious I understand, comment more re  attempting to point out:  iterations  being number of revolutions is a little  misleading in that one "rev" is as  defined by the angle set, not one full 360 degree revolution.  _Which to me is what is being suggested by answer?_ _btw_ almost commented re what ended up being answer too but thought surely not.. lol.