# How can I turn a mesh inside out

Tags: modeling, modifiers, mathematics

I have a mesh with bottle threads on the outside.  Now I would like to make / invert the threads so they appear on the inside to create the cap.   I tried using the boolean modifier and difference with another shape but it doesn't create the threads on the inside (it creates the difference of the threads, a gap).  How can I do this with Blender?  I'm also willing to do this mathematically if needed.

What I have.

[image: Threads outer]

I would like the threads to look like the image below.

[image: Threads inner]

If I scale it by -1 the threads aren't created on the inside. See image below.

[image: Scaled threads -1]

Comment: If that is some arrayed or spun profile, scale the profile by -1 on the axis to invert.  eg https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/192468/screw-modifier-creating-extra-faces

Comment: only scale one dimension, not all

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just to illustrate @batFINGER's comment.
You can flip the profile by scaling it by -1.

1. Select the profile
2. Set pivot point to one of the vertices through Pivot point > Active element
3. Scale it along X axis by -1

[image]